# Controlling the style of a label in a v-treeview in VuetifyJS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-treeview :items="items"></v-treeview>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

and the following Javascript:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Applications :',
        children: [
          { id: 2, name: 'Calendar : app' },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 15,
        name: 'Downloads :',
        children: [
          { id: 16, name: 'October : pdf' },
        ],
      }
    ],
  }),
})
```

Let's say that I want to make the font-size of the Downloads label bigger or make it bold.

Is this possible with Vuetify and it's v-treeview? If so, how? There does not appear to be a way to control the styling of the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything can be controlled in Vuetify. It's easier with some things and harder with others:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Applications :',
        children: [{
          id: 2,
          name: 'Calendar : app'
        }, ],
      },
      {
        id: 15,
        name: 'Downloads :',
        children: [{
          id: 16,
          name: 'October : pdf'
        }, ],
      }
    ],
  }),
})
```

```css
.large {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-treeview :items="items">
      <template v-slot:label="{ item }">
        <span
          :class="{ large: !!(item.id === 15) }"
        >
          {{ item.name }}
        </span>
      </template>
    </v-treeview>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Look at the **API** description on Vuetify's component pages, and look for `slots` - if a component has the slot you look for, then you can work with it quite easily. If not, then you may have to tweak classes or even the components.

`v-treeview`'s documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/

VTreeview has a `slot` called `label`. You can "invoke" that slot by:

```
<v-treeview :items="items">
  <template v-slot:label="{ item, leaf, selected, indeterminate, active, open }">
    <!-- your code comes here --->
  </template>
</v-treeview>
```

You can pass in `item`, `leaf`, `selected`, `indetermintae`, `active` or `open` props, that you can use in the scope of the `<template></template>`. In my snippet, we only needed the `item`, that's why I only passed that down.

My snippet only works, if you have an item with `id: 15` - but you can put any logic there: calling methods, computed properties, etc.

For more information you can look in [Vue scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) and [destructuring slot props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Destructuring-Slot-Props).

Answer (score 1):

You must to use the slot `label`. Try something like  this:

```html
<v-treeview :items="items">
  <template v-slot:label="{ item }">
    <span style="font-weight: bold">{{ item.name }}</span>
  </template>
</v-treeview>
```

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)